# Why Will Jest Not Run? "TypeError: environment.setup is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, babeljs, jestjs

really battling here.

My Circle CI tests have failed with a

```
FAIL  ./App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

I try to run Jest locally on my machine (a CRNA one) but i get the following error:

`TypeError: environment.setup is not a function`

So both of these appear to be node version/ES6/babel issues, right?

I battled through some errors before (`Path was expecting string` etc), which i got round by install jest-cli and changing node versions etc.

i am now on:
**node** v8.9.1
**npm** 5.5.1

But now i'm totally stumped.

So:

`TypeError: environment.setup is not a function` is specific to jest-cli package.

i've tried:

i) adding in the following to the jest config in pkg json:

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "testMatch": [
      "*.test.js",
      "**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(react-native|jest-cli)/)"
    ]
  }
```

(thought this might 'babel' the module, but alas no change in error msg)

ii) Changing versions of babel-core, installing babel-node-modules, changing versions of React Native, jest etc etc.  No joy.

Help?

Is there something i'm missing in terms of getting a Create React Native App project to run jest tests on node v5-v8?

Proper stumped and it's holding up getting my Circle CI set-up.

Send help or some sort of IPA ale to sooth my frustration.

Comment: Du you have an environment variable called setup defined? echo $setup

Comment: @PatrickHund draws a blank, mate. Is this something that’s usually an issue with CRNA vs jest?

Comment: No, just an attempt at troubleshooting.

Comment: ah thanks @PatrickHund - it seems to be something to do with Circle CI not knowing what Jest is ('module not found...' etc). But if install jest/note it in the pkg json, it *then* fails locally. So i'm just trying some things around maybe noting it in the pkg json, pushing, then removing it locally again.

Dunno, seems weird Circle would have such an issue with CRNA config.

Comment: If you figure it out, it would be super helpful if you answered your own question, I think it is interesting for other developers

Comment: will do @PatrickHund From the sh*t-tonne i've read: it's an issue with Jest versions, specific to CRNA and the es6 code within jest that isn't transpiled by babel (which ignores node_modules). once i've actually got it fully working, i'll answer it for sure. x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up getting this working by:

i) installing `babel-jest`

ii) `babel-preset-react-native` (instead of the stage-0 module)

iii) changing the test script to just `test: jest`

iv) removing env variable from .babelrc (so it's just `"presets": ["react-native"]` now)

v) changing my `config.yml` to a `circle.yml` (this got rid of a node version error)

vi) nuking node_modules, full `npm install` (/`yarn`)

vii) moved my `App.test.js` out of the root and into its own `__tests__/App.test.js` folder/location.

I think babel-jest was the main crux of it, but even then I was getting propTypes not found errors and had to check my peer dependencies, some of which needed updating past the beta versions of things I had been using.

**My package json:**

```
{
  "name": "MyAppName",
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.2.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.0",
    "eslint": "^4.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
    "flow-bin": "0.53.1",
    "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0",
    "sinon": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jest-cli": "^21.2.1",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.51.0"
  }
}
```